# Is router compulsory to host a server at my home PC

Tags: router, hosting, dynamic-dns

I know the requirements for hosting though I have a doubt whether router is really needed?
Compulsory things are access to the Internet, a web server, static IP (I will use dynamic DNS services like no-ip.org), and will get domain name from there only.

But is really a router required?

If I don't have a router its just a direct cable to my PC from ISP , so can I host a server using dynamic DNS services.
And I have only one pc at my home.

Answer (score 2):

Not really mandatory but it will possibly add a layer of protection to devices behind it on your home network.  Most home routers are very reasonably priced and add features that you may find useful or add protection to your home computer with things such as Stateful Packet Inspection (SPI) or URL Filtering.

You also need to determine if your ISP allows a server on their network.  Many block such traffic so your efforst may not give the result you want router or no router.

Comment: so how can i determine whether ISP would allow server or not (i dont want to ask them)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other PC at home, you don't need a router. You can build a firewall on your machine and will have protection (a firewall with NAT on the router would not be useless of course but I don't think it is a very big issue if it is a home server not dealing with financial or users info).

Now, regarding the ISP, some ISP do not allow many computers connected but this is not your case as you will use only machine (with 1 IP).

The other point regarding ISP is that many of them block the ports usually used by servers (80, 25, 110 for example) and your server (with or without router) won't be reachable on regular ports (you will need to include the port like this `http://www.site.com:8080` to reach it. There are a few workarounds (nothing very nice) to that like an external port forwarding service for example.

To test if your ISP blocks the port you need without asking them (I saw your comment ;)), you can put something to listen on port 80 (you didn't say your OS but for linux `nc -l 80` should do the trick or something similar) and from an external IP, issue `telnet your.ip 80` and see if it answers.

Anyways, this is not a very good way to host something more than personal data as if your machine breaks (or is stuck with an update) or your Internet goes down (or many other things), your server will be down. Have a look at your ISP speed limits too as usualy home internet is not adequate for servers. The download speed is ok but the upload maximum speed is normally a lot lower.

Comment: so its important that ISP allows port 80 traffic to host a server at home (doesn't matter whether i have a router or not). correct me if i understood wrong!!!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are a few workarounds but it is a lot better if port 80 is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

as long as your system is accessible from outside you can host a server.
but there will be quite a few issues

- The chances of you having a commercial connection at home are very less. The ISPs generally 
  prioritize the traffic of commercial clients over residential connections.
- http (port 80) may be blocked.
- your PC needs to run 24x7.
- The upload speed (important when you are hosting a server) will be on the lower side 
  for a non-commercial connection.